# How to set a fixed row length in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any method in Pandas that sets each row from a *pd.Series* column

```
    Column
1      253
2        7
3       12
```

into any fixed length? *Either an integer or a string.*

```
    Column
1      253
2      007
3      012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `str.zfill` vectorized string operation... But you need to convert the column to a string first.

```
df.Column.astype(str).str.zfill(3)

1    253
2    007
3    012
Name: Column, dtype: object
```

---

You can also apply a format string

```
df.Column.apply('{:03d}'.format)

1    253
2    007
3    012
Name: Column, dtype: object
```

---

**timing**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Column=np.random.randint(1000, size=10000)))


%timeit df.Column.apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(3))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.36 ms per loop

%timeit df.Column.astype(str).str.zfill(3)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.5 ms per loop

%timeit df.Column.apply('{:03d}'.format)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.03 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#Use zfill()

s.apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(3))
Out[942]: 
1    253
2    007
3    012
Name: Column, dtype: object
```